# css, js and image not loading in subdomain using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, subdomain

CSS,JS and Images are not loading with codeigniter on the subdomain created in Ubuntu.

https://fmbhq.duckdns.org/user/login

also https://fmbhq.duckdns.org is redirected to https://www.www.fmbhq.duckdns.org/fmbhq/index.php/fmbhq/index.php/

css file not loading https://fmbhq.duckdns.org/assets/css/font.css

My files are at /var/www/html/fmbhq

my .htaccess in fmbhq folder is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

My conf file under /etc/apache2/sites-available is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin support@weconnectdirect.com
ServerName fmbhq.duckdns.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fmbhq/index.php

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.fmbhq.duckdns.org [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =fmbhq.duckdns.org
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: How you are loading CSS,JS and Images files?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/font.css" type="text/css"/>

on webpage it shows as <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fmbhq.duckdns.org/assets/css/font.css" type="text/css"/>

Answer (score 0):

If your files are at `/var/www/html/fmbhq`, DocumentRoot in your conf file is wrong. it should be `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fmbhq`

Comment: tried changing to DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fmbhq and restarted apache2, but not working

Comment: please try removing `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)` from .htaccess $1 may not be available there